# How to extract data from a column with variable number of values in each row in a CSV file?

Tags: python, file, csv, variables

Basically I'm trying to add together the count column values of item columns with the same name in a csv file. I then need to sort the results in ascending alphabetic order by item column values. For example:

```
Leading Cause, Deaths
Diabetes Mellitus, 123
Influenza and Pneumonia, 325
Diabetes Mellitus, 100
```

I need to add the values 123 and 100 to get a new row for Diabetes.

**It should look like this:** 
    `Diabetes Mellitus, 223`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File)
    itemindex = sys.argv[2]
    countindex = sys.argv[3]
    item column = 0
    count column = 0
    first row = True
    dictionary = {}

    for row in reader:
       if firstrow == True:
          firstrow = False
          itemcolumn = row.index(itemindex)
          countcolumn = row.index(countindex)
       else:
           if item column in dictionary:
               # Add the item at the row's count column (converted to an int) to the
               # prexisting entry with that item column.
           else:
               #create a new entry in the dictionary

       print(itemindex + "," + countindex)

for key, value in sorted(dictionary)
    print(key + "," + value)
```

The commented parts are the ones I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is a specialized dictionary class, would make it easy:

```
import collections
import csv
import os
import sys

try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    itemindex = int(sys.argv[2])
    countindex = int(sys.argv[3])
except IndexError:
    print('Error:\n  Usage: {} <file name> <item index> <count index>'.format(
            os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))
    sys.exit(-1)

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)  # Skip first row.

    counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for row in reader:
        disease, deaths = row[itemindex], int(row[countindex])
        counter[disease] += deaths

for key, value in sorted(counter.items()):
    print('{}, {}'.format(key, value))
```

Sample usage:

```
python3 script_name.py diseases.csv 0 1
```

Sample output:

```
Diabetes Mellitus, 223
Influenza and Pneumonia, 325
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access you could use the pandas package to handle the csv.

Text file titled values.txt

```
Leading Cause, Deaths
Diabetes Mellitus, 123
Influenza and Pneumonia, 325
Diabetes Mellitus, 1008
```

The desired data frame can be achieved with:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('values.txt')
print(data)

sum_data = data.groupby(['Leading Cause']).sum()
print(sum_data)

print(sum_data.loc['Diabetes Mellitus'])
```

Which would output

```
             Leading Cause   Deaths
0        Diabetes Mellitus      123
1  Influenza and Pneumonia      325
2        Diabetes Mellitus     1008

                          Deaths
Leading Cause                   
Diabetes Mellitus           1131
Influenza and Pneumonia      325

 Deaths    1131
Name: Diabetes Mellitus, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `pandas` is a great package to manage data within csv files, and even for excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not using the libraries provided and just loop through the data as text.  Parsing the text.